# Measuring Loading time of a web page (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, testing, performance, html

I would like to know if there is a simple way of measuring the time it takes from when you hit Enter, to the time where a web page is fully displayed/loaded. Would I need to use a Timer for this, or are there existing features built into the Web Browser control (or .net framework) that I have missed out on?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control over the ASP.NET page, you could turn on Trace. There you will get a bunch of information about the Page lifecycle( including time stamps), and other useful profiling information.

Turn on trace for a page in the `Page` directive at the top of your aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

Or dynamically in code:

```
Trace.IsEnabled = true;
```

Or globally in the app setting this in web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(VS.71).aspx) for Trace.

Comment: Thank you for your help, awe. Cool link :)

Comment: But this only shows the time until asp.net is done with the request. You miss the time it takes to send this to the browser and have it rendered there.

Comment: ...you also have no feedback on the complexity of the DOM. A request might complete fast enough on the server but the browser is not prepared to handle all those DOM elements. The browser might even crash if you strain it enough and I've seen this first hand. There's also true profiling APIs that you can use. I believe IE9 has introduced a profiling API you could access from JavaScript. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974378(v=vs.85).aspx#_webperf

Answer (score 5):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (extension for Firefox) has a timing panel, under the "Net" tab.

Comment: Why the downvote for something that shows the time until the page is fully displayed?

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can inspect all web requests and show you the relevant timings.

Comment: Any reason for the drive-by -1?

Answer (score 1):

[Dynatrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) is quite a powerful tool for diagnosticing performance issues on client side.

In combination with `Fiddler` it gives you the full timeframe from initial `HTTP` request up to the moment the rendering is completed in the `webbrowser`. It also features some auto diagnostics, where it informs the user about any `hotstops/bottlenecks` found in the `HTML/Javascript` code.

Till I find something better, this application is part of my standard toolset whenever I have to investigate performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search reveals all :)

[Timing a Page Load C#](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/25028-Checkout-page-load-time.aspx)

Essentialy you are just recording the time at the start of Page_Load and at the end and using some simple math to work out the difference, there is your load time

Comment: The OP is not in asp.net land. He wants to time how long it takes for a webbrowser control to load some page.

Comment: Misunderstood, fair one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some RUM tool to measure loading time. This method is accurate as it use navigation api on browser and timings are measured from perspective of users. Here is an simple rum tool http://gear5.me and a more complex one : http://newrelic.com